# DHT22 sensors show 'nan' when uploading to MQTT

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt

I am trying to send value from DHT22 with nodemcu-ESP8266 to mosquito broker, and I am currently using MQTT explorer. However, my DHT22 detected nan value. I know that there are no problems with the wire connections and the the board in general, because I later verified with another program.
What could be the problems? I know about the function called isnan(), it is not what I am looking for.

The faulty program, DHT22 shows nan value.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include "DHT.h"


// WiFi
const char *ssid = "xxx"; // Enter your WiFi name
const char *password = "xxx";  // Enter WiFi password
// MQTT Broker
const char *mqtt_broker = "xxx"; // Enter your WiFi or Ethernet IP
const char *topic = "test/temperature & humidity";
const int mqtt_port = 1883;

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321
uint8_t DHTPin = D7;
DHT dht(DHTPin, DHTTYPE);

float temperature;
float humidity;
char msg[50];

void setup() {
  // Set software serial baud to 115200;
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // connecting to a WiFi network
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");

  //connecting to a mqtt broker
  client.setServer(mqtt_broker, mqtt_port);
  client.setCallback(callback);

  while (!client.connected()) {
    String client_id = "esp8266-client-";
    client_id += String(WiFi.macAddress());

    Serial.printf("The client %s connects to mosquitto mqtt broker\n", client_id.c_str());

    if (client.connect(client_id.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("Public mosquitto broker connected");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed with state ");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      delay(2000);
    }
  }

  String msg = "real time temperature: ";
  msg = msg + dht.readTemperature();
  msg = msg + " C ;real time Humidity: " ;
  msg = msg + dht.readHumidity() ;
  msg = msg + "%";
  char message[58];
  msg.toCharArray(message, 58);

  Serial.println(message);

  // publish and subscribe
  client.publish(topic, message);
  client.subscribe(topic);
} /* end of void setup() */

void callback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived in topic: ");
  Serial.println(topic);
  Serial.print("Message:");

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char) payload[i]);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(" - - - - - - - - - - - -");
}
void loop() {
  client.loop();
}
```

The verification program showed there are no problems with DHT22, can ignore.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include "DHT.h"

// Uncomment one of the lines below for whatever DHT sensor type you're using!
//#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
//#define DHTTYPE DHT21   // DHT 21 (AM2301)
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321

/*Put your SSID & Password*/
const char* ssid = "xxx";  // Enter SSID here
const char* password = "xxxx";  //Enter Password here

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

// DHT Sensor
uint8_t DHTPin = D7;

// Initialize DHT sensor.
DHT dht(DHTPin, DHTTYPE);

float Temperature;
float Humidity;
float temp;
float hum;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  pinMode(DHTPin, INPUT);

  dht.begin();

  Serial.println("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  //connect to your local wi-fi network
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  //check wi-fi is connected to wi-fi network
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected..!");
  Serial.print("Got IP: ");  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");

  temp = temp_detect();
  hum = hum_detect();
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.println("degree celsius");
  Serial.print(hum);
  Serial.println("%");
}
void loop() {

  server.handleClient();

}

void handle_OnConnect() {

  Temperature = dht.readTemperature(); // Gets the values of the temperature
  Humidity = dht.readHumidity(); // Gets the values of the humidity
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(Temperature, Humidity));
  Serial.print(Temperature);
  Serial.print(Humidity);
}

float temp_detect() {
  float temperature1;
  temperature1 = dht.readTemperature();
  return temperature1;
}

float hum_detect() {
  float humidity1;
  humidity1 = dht.readHumidity();
  return humidity1;
}

void handle_NotFound() {
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}


/*
CAN IGNORE THIS PART, JUST HTML CODE

*/
String SendHTML(float Temperaturestat, float Humiditystat) {
  String ptr = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html>\n";
  ptr += "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">\n";
  ptr += "<title>ESP8266 Weather Report</title>\n";
  ptr += "<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}\n";
  ptr += "body{margin-top: 50px;} h1 {color: #444444;margin: 50px auto 30px;}\n";
  ptr += "p {font-size: 24px;color: #444444;margin-bottom: 10px;}\n";
  ptr += "</style>\n";
  ptr += "</head>\n";
  ptr += "<body>\n";
  ptr += "<div id=\"webpage\">\n";
  ptr += "<h1>ESP8266 NodeMCU Weather Report</h1>\n";

  ptr += "<p>Temperature: ";
  ptr += (int)Temperaturestat;
  ptr += "°C</p>";
  ptr += "<p>Humidity: ";
  ptr += (int)Humiditystat;
  ptr += "%</p>";

  ptr += "</div>\n";
  ptr += "</body>\n";
  ptr += "</html>\n";
  return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program that worked contains this code which is relevant:

```
  pinMode(DHTPin, INPUT);

  dht.begin();
```

The program that didn't doesn't have those lines of code. I'm not sure which DHT library you're using so I can't say for sure if you need the `pinMode()` call but you definitely need the `dht.begin()` call. Add those lines to `setup()` before you try to use the sensor.

This is something you can easily discover for yourself by reading the two programs and comparing them.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I only need to add `dht.begin()`, no need for `pinMode`

Answer (score 0):

I also had "nan" value problem. I selected my board in IDE as nodemcu-0.9 (ESP-12) but I had nodemcu-1.0 (ESP-12E). Make sure you select the right board before uploading your code.